# Azure Application Insights Web test result hanging with "loading..." message

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

I have a web test that is running in Azure Application Insights, which displays the results in a scattergraph:

[image]

Clicking on any given test on the graph gives a results page, which should be populated with the test results like the following:

[image]

The above image is taken from my dev environment where everything works fine. For the integration environment I cloned the webtest powering the dev environment, changed the url to point at the integration endpoint with the correct credentials.

The test runs fine as I can see a raft of successful tests in the scattergraph, however when I click on the test to view the results page I get the following:

[image]

The loading message never updates, it just hangs forever even if I go away and come back to it hours later.

I have check all the config that I can see and ensured that the Webtest is set up right but cannot see anything obviously wrong.

What could be causing this? How does Azure know which set of results to return for a given web test? Is it name or Id driven perhaps?

Comment: There is an option to download VS Web Test Result to open it in Visual Studio. Can you please check whether download also hangs for you?

Comment: @ZakiMa I can see that there is an option to open the result in Visual Studio, but when I click that nothing happens. I don't see a "download VS Web test Result" option

Comment: one other suggestion is to use your browser's F12 tools and see if you're getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @JohnGardner There was an error in the console, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug in the search request that the Azure portal makes when clicking any of the tests in the graph.

An 500 response was being thrown and causing the "loading..." message to hang:

```
{ 
  "code":"One or more errors occurred.",
  "message":"One or more errors occurred.",
  "innererror":{
      "diagnosticcontext":"xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx", 
       "time":"2017-04-10T08:13:01.8861938Z"
   }
}
```

The root of the problem is that upper case characters are not handled in the search request, so if your web test names are not all lower case the internal server error is returned and the portal UI hang occurs.

Web tests created through the portal have the lower case naming convention enforced via a validation rule in the UI, but as I had created my tests via ARM template, there was no indication that upper case characters should not be used.

Until the bug is fixed, if you are creating tests via ARM templates, ensure that the following values do not contain upper case characters:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
      "AvailabilityTestName": {
          "value": "lower-cased-name"
   },
      "WebTestResourceName": {
          "value": "lower-cased-name"
   },
```

Comment: i'll forward this on to the team that owns webtests and see if it is intentional, and needs to be documented, or unintentional, or something that the backend should just be doing for you.